# Impact of location access (global setting in device's settings) on battery power consumption when there are no apps accessing it?

Tags: battery, battery-life, android-11, geolocation

I vaguely remember a post whose author stated that having a global location access setting in an off state does not discharge an antenna and it continues working in a "passive mode".

So the only change that is made to device's functioning when turning on the setting is that it allows apps to request high-power consumption geolocation (provided that they have the individual per-app permission). For example, Google Maps.

Does that mean that there is no difference in battery power consumption between having it on and off unless you are using an app that requests your geolocation (such as Google Maps)?

Answer (score 3):

It does consume battery whether you are using the app or not but the consumption may be lesser.

From [Access location in the background](https://developer.android.com/training/location/background#:%7E:text=Background%20location%20access%20checklist,-Use%20the%20following&text=Verify%20that%20your%20app%20requires,a%20feature%20that%20requires%20it), which describes different types of location access permissions:

> If background location access is essential for your app, keep in mind that Android **preserves device battery life** by setting **background location limits** on devices that run Android 8.0 (API level 26) and higher. On these versions of Android, if your app is running in the background, it can receive location **updates only a few times each hour**. [Learn more about background location limits](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/background-location-limits)

(Emphasis supplied)

This behavior may vary if your device is running lower than Android 8.

Comment: And if an app doesn't have the "always allow" location access permission? I guess it means that it can't pull the geoinfo in background? I guess it means that if there are no apps that have the permission then there are no difference between having GA on and off all the time unless you are using Google maps

Comment: On recent Android versions, you can grant it location access"only while using the app", so it will use power//I am not sure of the answer to your question since you haven't mentioned Android version and maybe someone with app development background can better answer //You can add your device version and make in the tags//I see that you edited your comment while I was responding. To my mind once you have global access enabled there will always be **some power consumption.** Think of "find my device" feature

Comment: Well, yeah, that is what I am talking about, lol, you could have figured that I actually have A11 since I mentioned "always allow" setting which wasn't there in older versions

Comment: So you got your answer I guess. I added the tag

Comment: Nah, not quite, what if I have FMD off as well? So basically: FMD off + no apps in "always allow location" section + not using (like literally not having it's main screen opened) an app that requests geolocation such as GMaps = X. X - does it make difference to have a global GA on and off (provided that those conds are met)?

Comment: Yes, some power will still be drawn since *location updates only a few times each hour* as quoted in the answer

Comment: Sorry, but I am not sure what you are referring to by "location updates"? In your quotation it is evident that they mean the API requests made by applications. And that the cap introduced in 8th iteration of Android OS will make it so that too frequent requests will return errors if made by an app. However, if I understand correctly, those will always return errors if the access is denied (the app runs in background and the "always" switch is off). So in my case it makes it so that "location updates" never happen unless the app is working in foreground (in use, main screen open)

Comment: Oh sorry misunderstood you, your assumption is correct AFAIK ( I am not a developer)

Comment: @infinitieunique some system apps like **Settings** cannot have the Location permission disabled (i.e. always on), at least on Pixel 3a, Android 12. It also affects the Night Light with the sunrise/sunset schedule; if it doesn't get the updated location (even in the background), then [it might not work](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/252376/44325).

Comment: So are you suggesting that having the global GA off denies the permission even for them? But that is just hilarious, like: no dude you can't deny the permission, but actually you CAN

Comment: Please tag the person, I presume this was meant for @AndrewT. In any case see his linked answer and my comments underneath that

Comment: @infinitieunique not exactly. Location service is the one that updates and saves/provides the location, while permission is just that, permission for an app to read the currently saved location from the location service and request the location service to get the latest location.

Comment: @Andrew T. so is antenna physically discharged when turning off the global location setting switch or not? Also, can you use more precise and technical terms? I am guessing by "service" you mean process in system that has direct access to antenna driver since it's system one... So when you turn the switch off the process stops and even those system apps who have the irrevocable all-time access to location are left with nothing to query? But then again, we are talking about system apps here, can't they just start it regardless since they have system privileges... So many questions